# Django - How can I "upgrade" user type?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-users

I have two models, Buyer and Merchant with the default user type after the account creation being Buyer.

```
# Abstract User
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


# Buyer
class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

    # items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'


# Merchant
class Merchant(models.Model):  # items
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    pgp = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    # image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

And I have a become-a-merchant.html template in which I would like to make the Buyer be able to become a Merchant after checking a checkbox and pressing a button.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check">
<label for="checkbox">Become a merchant.</label>
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Upgrade</button>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I do a form that upgrades my user type.

Answer (score 0):

You have submitted too little information on whether you are handling this with a `function` or a `generic class`. Also, I have a feeling that you don't need to do so many `classes` if you are using `flags` in user. If it's the `generic class`, you'll need to update the `User` class this way.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from .models import User # or other location

# model
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['is_buyer, is_merchant']

# template
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview).

Comment: I was getting an Unknown field(s) (is_buyer, is_merchant) specified for User error. And then edited the fields to fields = ['is_buyer', 'is_merchant'].

Comment: It is not possible that the fields are unknown. You must have made a mistake somewhere. Make sure you correctly include `from .models import User # or other location`. If it still doesn't work, include the code and screenshots.

Comment: I'm getting the error: Generic detail view UserUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: Show your `urls.py`